How to copy a phone number from PC and paste it on Android phone to make a call?
My job is to call numbers that are in an excel sheet or numbers on web pages. I'm tired of having to look at the PC screen and typing the phone number on my android phone. I wish if I can click a "call" button on my PC to make a phone call on my phone.
It's okay for me to speak though my phone's mic and listen to my phone's speaker. So, I don't need the call to be through my PC. I just need to transfer the number from PC to phone.
Saving numbers would be a plus for me.
Is there a free software that does so?
Google voice doesn't work in Egypt.

For what system? Windows I assume since Excel was mentioned?

Yes, its windows

The program "KDE Connect" is able to synchronise clipboards of devices connected to the same network. I use it to copy URLs between my computer and phone. However it cannot initiate phone calls directly from a computer.
Further instructions: https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect/en

With Microsoft Link and you can make a direkt call via this software with your phone.
Copy the number, paste it into the search field and click on the green button to start the call.

The Link softwrae communicate directly with your phone. In my case a Samsung phone...


You could try Join. It's available on all popular systems and can synchronize clipboard. It also integrates heavily with Tasker which can process the data in various ways:

detect phone numbers
use any app to call someone

etc. There are tons of various possibilities if you learn both of these tools.
